# PHP Sessions Remove Cart Iitems

Tags: php, session, cart

I have been searching around for help but can't find anything that will fix my problem

I have manipulated a cart code to serve a different a purpose Im bulging a role-play assistance site www.rptoolkit.com/encounter where you add NPC's to the encounter (Cart) and you can then remove them when needed, the site is online if you want to check

the issue is script works perfectly fine in XXMP hosting on my local host but online live, if i add 4 people to the list and try to delete 1 they all clear and the first line gets duplicated (feel free to test)

below is my script code i have used for the delete item button

```
<h1>Curent Encounter</h1>
 <div class="encounter-table">
    <?php
    $current_url = base64_encode($url="http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    if(isset($_SESSION["encounter"]))
    {

        $cart_items = 0;
        foreach ($_SESSION["encounter"] as $cart_itm)   
        {
           $id = $cart_itm["code"];
           $results = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE id='$id' LIMIT 1");
           $obj = $results->fetch_object();

    echo '<td><span> 
<a href="include/encounter_remove.php?removep='.$cart_itm["code"].'&return_url='.$current_url.'"><img src="images/icon_delete.gif" alt="Delete"><
/a></span></td>';
```

and below is the code I have to remove items from the encounter (cart)

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once("config.php");

//remove item from encounter
if(isset($_GET["removep"]) && isset($_GET["return_url"]) && isset($_SESSION["encounter"]))
{
    $id = $_GET["removep"]; //get the product code to remove
    $return_url = base64_decode($_GET["return_url"]); //get return url


    foreach ($_SESSION["encounter"] as $cart_itm) //loop through session array var
        {
        if($cart_itm["code"]!=$id){ //item does,t exist in the list
            $product[ ] = array('code'=>$cart_itm["code"]);
            }

        //create a new product list for cart
        $_SESSION["encounter"] = $product;
        }

    //redirect back to original page
    header('Location:'.$return_url);
}
?>
```

I would love any help or advise i can I've to fix it, I don't know if its coming downy to the different PHP versions from my XXMP to the server possibly?

Thanks again,
Trev

Answer (score 0):

Session variable size can be limited by the browser. Depending on how much data is stored in `$_SESSION['encounter'], you may be reaching the limit. Consider only storing a id numbers or something similar instead of more complex objects and/or arrays.